# Audio does not play when i load it from the database through AJAX. The control appears but audio doesnt play

Tags: ajax, html5-audio

The audio files when loaded directly through php, plays. But when i load it through AJAX, it does not. What is the possible cause for it?

```
     $.ajax({

    url: 'recommend.php',
    type: 'post',
    success:function(response){


            var data= JSON.parse(response);
            if (data.saveEREG == 1){

                var displayArea = document.getElementById('displayArea');
                 var song_count = data.count;
                for (var i=0; i< song_count; i++)
                {
                    var div = document.createElement('div');

                    div.setAttribute("class","col-sm-4");
                    div.setAttribute("height","100px;");

                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.setAttribute("src",data.image_url[i]);

                    var aud_div = document.createElement('div');
                    aud_div.setAttribute("class","audio");
                    aud_div.setAttribute("height","50px;");
                    //aud_div.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red;")
                    var aud = document.createElement('AUDIO');
                    aud.src = data.song_url;
                    aud.setAttribute("controls", "controls");

                    var div_movie = document.createElement('div');
                    div_movie.setAttribute("class","movie_choice");
                    //var h5 = document.createElement('h5');

                    var div_rate = document.createElement('div');
                    div_rate.setAttribute("class","rate_widget")
                    div_rate.setAttribute("id",data.song[i]);
                    var star1 = document.createElement('div');
                    star1.setAttribute("class","star_1 ratings_stars");

                    var star2 = document.createElement('div');
                    star2.setAttribute("class","star_2 ratings_stars");

                    var star3 = document.createElement('div');
                    star3.setAttribute("class","star_3 ratings_stars");

                    var star4 = document.createElement('div');
                    star4.setAttribute("class","star_4 ratings_stars");

                    var star5 = document.createElement('div');
                    star5.setAttribute("class","star_5 ratings_stars");

                    var votes = document.createElement('div');
                    votes.setAttribute("class","total_votes");




                    displayArea.appendChild(div);

                    div.appendChild(img);
                    div.appendChild(aud_div);

                    aud_div.appendChild(aud);
                    div.appendChild(div_movie);
                    //div.appendChild(h5);
                    div_movie.appendChild(div_rate);
                    div_rate.appendChild(star1);
                    div_rate.appendChild(star2);
                    div_rate.appendChild(star3);
                    div_rate.appendChild(star4);
                    div_rate.appendChild(star5);
                    div_rate.appendChild(votes);
                }
```

The data.song_url is fetched from the database and is something like this http://127.0.0.1/ektara/uploads/01 Final Masquerade.mp3

Comment: where is your code

Comment: How did you stored the audio file in your DB? Also place a code please from what you have tried.

Comment: @NavnitMishra  i have added the code. Sorry for not posting it before. i didn't think it was required

Comment: @NavnitMishra i have just added a snippet. Not the entire ajax block. The rest is irrelevant.

Comment: it's oky let me check

Comment: @C0dekid.php The same songs when i load through a simple php request when the page loads, it plays. But when i try loading it through ajax, it does not.

Comment: any js warring or error in your console

Comment: @NavnitMishra This is the error in the console

GET http://127.0.0.1/ektara/uploads/01%20Final%20Masquerade.mp3,http://127.0.0.…reex].mp3,http://127.0.0.1/ektara/uploads/silverchair-cicada[mp3freex].mp3

Comment: js check kro yar  file nhi mil rhe hai